# Error in json decode

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I am sending php array as json format, but I was unable to decode the value. 
Here is how I made the array

```
    $ads = $atts['ads'];
    if (sizeof($ads) > 0) {
    foreach($ads as $social_item) {
        $sdbr = $social_item['sidebar'];
        $pno = $social_item['no'];
        $out[$sdbr] = $pno;
    }
}
```

Which output

```
array (
  'Full width ad 1' => 2,
  'sidebar-1' => 3,
)
```

Now I have json encode it

```
$myJSON = json_encode($out);
```

The json formatted value `{"Full width ad 1":2,"sidebar-1":3}`
Then I am passing it through data attribute value

```
echo "<div data-ad = '$myJSON' class='ash_loadmore'><span>LOAD MORE</span>
</div>";
```

The out that I have got

```
$ad = $_POST['ad'];
array (
  'Full width ad 1' => '2',
  'sidebar-1' => '3',
)
```

So now time for decode the output

```
    $out = json_decode($ad,TRUE);
    var_dump($out); // Returns NULL although the array value is present
```

But if I put the json format data it works fine

```
    $out = json_decode('{"Full width ad 1":2,"sidebar-1":3}',TRUE);
    var_dump($out);
```

I suspect before json encode the array `array(2) { ["Full width ad 1"]=> int(2) ["sidebar-1"]=> int(3) }` value is `int` but I am getting value as `string` `array(2) { ["Full width ad 1"]=> string(1) "2" ["sidebar-1"]=> string(1) "3" }`

What's wrong doing by me?

Comment: you said `$ad = $_POST['ad'];`? how you are passing data? through ajax? because `data-ad` never pass through normal form post(refresh page).So if you used ajax then add that code also in your html

Comment: If `$ad` already outputs `array(...)`, it's not JSON anymore.

Comment: I am sending using ajax and it's in wordpress environment

Comment: @deceze Yes I think json format is corrupted.

Comment: It's not "corrupted", it has been interpreted as JSON at some point and turned into a simple array again.

Answer (score 4):

After this step:

```
$ad = $_POST['ad'];
array (
  'Full width ad 1' => '2',
  'sidebar-1' => '3',
)
```

you see in the output that this is already a php array, so any json-decode method will fail (this is no json).

You can work with the array right away, depending what you want to do ;)

Comment: It's not possible to send array value to server without using json encode or serialize

Comment: @SadiaMehjabin It's not about to post TO a server, but receive data from a incoming POST (see $_POST Supervaraibale). So, script is already receiving the data and so, the data is a php-array and one can work with it right away ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that putting serialized JSON in html attribute could cause you a problem.

The reason why it can cause the problem is because your JSON could contain characters like **"** or **'** and it your output so it could corrupt your HTML syntax.

I guess you are sending that JSON via AJAX back to some PHP script, so reading JSON from corrupted HTML element could fetch invalid JSON data.

Solution to this problem is to use...

`$myJSON = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);`

... before outputing it into HTML. This will encode only quote characters.

You should also decode it on your PHP endpoint by using...

```
$ad = html_entity_decode($ad, ENT_QUOTES);
$out = json_decode($ad,TRUE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I applied it but no luck

Comment: No problem. As @Paladin said, if your variable $ad already has an array, there is no need for decoding JSON :) If those integers casted to string troubles you, it could be that your integers are casted in your JS during AJAX call. You can easily verify it in browser's network tools.